# Things to consider while upgrading to domino 9.0 from domino 8.5.3?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Need suggestions regarding upgrading our servers from 8.5.3 to 9.0

Currently our domino server and notes client that developers using are of version 8.5.3 with UP1. 
I saw there are many new features and useful fixes done 9.0.

We are planning to upgrade to 9.0. Please let me know what the things to be consider for successful upgrade, what will happen to databases created in 8.5.3, and does controls used from Extension library? 
Any other important points to be considered for this.

Comment: added lotus-domino tag as "xpages" holds rather app dev centric topics

Comment: This is more of a forum question than stackoverflow, which is intended for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

The general upgrade questions better belong onto the [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) forum. However there are a few things you want to look at when upgrading to 9.x:

- Make it the latest version: 9.0.1
- There can be only one: make sure that you don't carry the 8.5x Extlib forward. The 9.0 library contains all 8.x controls. Check if you had to "hack around" some of the behaviours and retest those
- Take advantage of the new [OpenNTF Domino API](https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino)
- Use the new [IBM OneUI 3.0.2](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/index.htm) (unless your are into Bootstrap of course)
- Use the new ability to send embedded experience eMails
- Recheck that you use VersionControl and ODS51/52 on all your databases
- Boost your [Designer Performance](http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-9E3U72) thx @timtripcony

... and use [the upgrade cheat sheet](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8C6BCH) - works well for any version